# Stress test on website contains video

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

I was using jmeter to stress test my website. But there is website containing videos played by jwplayer. When i send requests it only loads page not playing video. Is there any way to test the page with video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on jwplayer (only just heard of it) but I'll take a guess that it is loading the video through some sort of JavaScript/jquery/AJAX mechanism.

From what I understand Jmeter does not process these requests when you fire of a GET request to a page as it is NOT a real browser! If you want to force one of these elements to load * then you must make another GET request with the URL to that element only. On the site I test we have several AJAX elements that I have to test in this way, extracting the dynamic URL from the previous page and using that to load the next one.

*is your website actually hosting the videos, or just linking to a service hosting them? If the latter, there is no point to load testing the videos.

Comment: Yes i already did what you said. Jmeter couldn't play a video, no matter what player used. Yes my video hosted on local server. After all this is correct answer.